# Same zsh config acting differently on different machines

Tags: shell, zsh

I have the following config for zsh that I use on both my laptop and remote machine. I have all my config files put in a git repository that is cloned into `~/.zsh` and symlinked into `~`.

```
autoload -Uz promptinit
promptinit

HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt appendhistory autocd extendedglob nomatch notify
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/pkhorsand/.zshrc'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit -i -u -C

# load antigen
source $HOME/.zsh/antigen.zsh

# Load the oh-my-zsh's library.
antigen use oh-my-zsh

# Bundles from the default repo (robbyrussell's oh-my-zsh).
# antigen bundle git
antigen bundle heroku
# antigen bundle pip
# antigen bundle lein
# antigen bundle command-not-found
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

# Load the theme.
antigen theme robbyrussell
antigen theme https://github.com/caiogondim/bullet-train-oh-my-zsh-theme bullet-train

# Tell Antigen that you're done.
antigen apply

BULLETTRAIN_VIRTUALENV_BG="green"
BULLETTRAIN_VIRTUALENV_PREFIX=""
BULLETTRAIN_GIT_COLORIZE_DIRTY=true
BULLETTRAIN_GIT_DIRTY=""
BULLETTRAIN_GIT_EXTENDED=false
BULLETTRAIN_GIT_CLEAN=""
BULLETTRAIN_PROMPT_ORDER=(
    context
    dir
    virtualenv
    git
    time
)

source "$HOME/.zsh/.alias"
source "$HOME/.zsh/.profile.local"
```

On my MacBook Pro running `zsh 5.3` (system default) command history completion works properly. If I type something and press the arrow keys it will cycle through commands in my history that have it as a prefix. The remote machine running `Ubuntu 14.0` and `zsh 5.5.1` (installed manually and not through `apt`) however simply cycles the history regardless of what I have typed.

I use `antigen` as the plugin manager whose source is also included in the same repository (hence both installation use the same version of it). This behavior is really confusing as the same `.zshrc` should imply the same behavior in my opinion. Or should it?

** Update: The `site-functions` directory on my Mac includes a couple entries for `_brew` and `_brew_cask` (this is a relatively new machine with not much installed) while the one on the remote is empty.

Comment: Might be a silly question but: Did you install your plugins on to the other machines?

Comment: @Jarco Yeah, obviously. The `antigen` commands take care of themselves.